# How to summon this sequence of stacked mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a costum map and I want to summon this kind of "mob tower"

```
 M
---
 V
---
 B
```

Where `M`= Invisible Mooshroom, `V`=Villager and `B`=bat. `---` are layers of obsidian blocks that already exists in the world.

The Villager is used for some mob tracking magic using Zombies. The bat is for randomizing the movement of the stack and the invisible Mooshroom is used for targeting other commands. There should also be a way to kill a single stack (i.e. kill Mooshroom, Villager and Bat, without killing all of them.

The logic of the game I try to make is this:

1. Four stacks will be summoned on the field.
2. After a random time the mooshroom closest to the center of the field will explode, I teleport primed TNT to it.
3. The villager and the bat of that stack will be killed as well as every zombie in the game.
4. The next closest stack will do the same until all 4 stacks are gone.

I have tried summoning different stacks and watching some tutorials but I have major trouble getting the spacing right, I just can't get any space between them. Also I forgot how an effect is added. I did found that invisibility is effect 23 or something (I can figure that out myself, don't even worry about it) but I don't know the syntax.

Can someone just tell me the commands for spawning and killing the stack?

Comment: I'm not sure about exact spacing but try stacking invisible armor stand between mobs. And http://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/ is a very good tool for generating various commands.

Comment: armor stands don't clip the block so I can't use them

Comment: Minecraft does not take account of riders' collision with blocks. They will clip through(and possibly take suffocation damage) if the ridden entity goes under the block.

Comment: okay, then the only problem is that my world uses single layer bocks but the armour stand takes up 2 blocks

Comment: Use `Riding:{id:` for stacking mobs

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you are asking for (no offense, but your grammar is a bit hard to understand, when accompanied with the spelling...). Do you want to create a stack of mobs with 2 obsidian flying in the middle?? Also, I don't understand the part "there should be a way to kill all 3 mobs without the other stacks being killed" and "killed will be the closesed stack to a certain point X,Y,Z."

Comment: no the obsidian is a normal block. There will be four stacks of these and one of them will be removed every time after a certain event. For example the one closest to 100, 20, -100 as coordinates

Comment: I see. But when an obsidian is a normal block you can't place it like an entity. It can't freely move like the bats...

Comment: I know but they act as seperation so for example the player does not see the vat and zombie and the vat does not fly away

Comment: Oh so you are doing a mob tower which will not move? I'm sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: No they will move right? the obsidian isn't part of the stack. They are fixed but they aren't part of this stack. I edited my question a bit so you may have a better idea of what's going on here.

Comment: First of all: Are you talking about Mooshrooms, as in mushroom cows? Secondly: It looks like you are spawning a bat, an Obsidian Block over the bat, Two stacked Villagers, another obsidian block and two Mooshrooms, which makes little sense. What I understand is that you have a three layer "level" made from obsidian (because explosions) and want to summon a bat on layer 0 to make the thing do a randomwalk, a villager on layer 1 to attract zombies and an invisible mooshroom on level 2, for the explosion targeting. Is that correct?

Comment: Perfect. That's is exactly correct

Comment: For the killing part you can do `/kill @e[type=<Entity>,c=<How many you wanna kill>]`

Comment: does this mean that as if I set c=1 it will kill the closest

Comment: It will search for the closest mob specified from the command block and kill maximum one specified mob.

Comment: I think you can separate stacked mobs with summoning some entities which height is approx. 1 block high, but then the mob will suffocate... Also, do you want the stacks to spread randomly on the field?

Comment: that might be good but for now let's say that the bats will do that. there is some time between the first and last explosion

Comment: I found a solution to separate the entities. Use a slime.

Comment: But another problem is, as bats are very small, they can fly up and down between a 1 block space, making it almost impossible to make the spacing right. Any suggestions for this? I have a basic answer already but I can't fix this problem.

Comment: Indeed they have like a height of 0.5. I can check if a half step works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/summon MushroomCow ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:100000,Amplifier:1,HideParticles:1}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Villager",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Bat",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}]}}}}}`

Explanation:

I used a spider to separate the mobs in the end as it's exactly 1 block tall. It is invulnerable to suffocation (because it has like 10000 health).

Also, all mobs have 10000 health, so even when they are stuck in a block because of the bat, they don't die. Change health by changing the number of `baseHealth` in this section: `Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:<HP>}]`

To kill the whole stack, first off, you have to make sure all commands blocks are activated at the very same time -- exact same time, or it may result in idling totems of mob towers. Then type in the command `/kill @e[type=Bat,c=1,r=<size of the field>]` in command block `A`, `/kill @e[type=Villager,c=1,r=<size of the field>]` in `B`, `/kill @e[type=Mooshroom,c=1,r=<size of the field>]` in `C` and `/kill @e[type=Spider,c=2,r=<size of the field>]` in `D`. Then you should be able to kill the whole stack.

I don't have a computer now so I cannot check the code, but feel free to tell me if it worked or not. Thanks!

Comment: I will see if it works

Comment: Edited: Added double quotation mark after `id:"Bat`

Comment: Edited: Changed to `MushroomCow`

Comment: does the villager interfeer with a preasure plate

Comment: Yes. All pressure plates react to villagers

Comment: If I answered your question, please press the tick. ;)

Comment: I don't know yet, I can't try before tomorrow so then I might thick, if it works

Answer (score -2):

if you want to summon anything i reccomend you use this site. i used mcstacker in the past, but this is much better, and more user-freindly. http://www.summon-helper.net/entityEditor.html?entityId=ArmorStand