# What's wrong with this code

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`/summon Mooshroom ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:100000,Amplifier:1,HideParticles:1}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Villager,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Bat",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}]}}}}}`

In the command block console it says:

`data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced quotation:{ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:100000,Amplifier:1,HideParticles:1}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Villager,Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Bat",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}]}}}}}`

What's wrong?

Comment: hey that is from my question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194333/how-to-summon-this-sequence-of-stacked-mobs there is nothing wrong with it in my question

Comment: I'm just asking why the code is wrong so that I can help.

Comment: ahh I was wondering why i saw it twice I didn't saw you are the same guy who helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things. First of all, a mooshroom is called a MushroomCow in the code. Second of all, you missed a quotation mark after 'Villager'.

```
/summon MushroomCow ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:100000,Amplifier:1,HideParticles:1}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Villager",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Bat",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}]}}}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed the " in your command after Villager.

> ..."Villager<---HERE

so, the command is

> /summon Mooshroom ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:100000,Amplifier:1,HideParticles:1}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Villager",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Spider",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}],Riding:{id:"Bat",Attributes:[{Name:"generic.maxHealth",Base:10000}]}}}}}

(This does not work in 1.12.1)